# You approved a clear non-answer

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I've done review on Stack Overflow recently and as far as I know have passed all the tests **recently** without failing any of them (recently). Yesterday I've completed all the maximum number of reviews per a session and when I came back today to review it said:

> You approved a clear non-answer:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12860815 and have
>   repeatedly failed audits in a row. Please be more careful when
>   reviewing.
>
> Come back on Jul 30 at 19:06 to continue reviewing.

What is the reason for this? I didn't fail any of tests recently; I'm 100% sure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You were manually banned from review by a moderator for [the linked review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12860815). For the record, this is the answer:

[image]

You reviewed this as "Looks OK". A moderator saw that review and enforced a short break from review.

You were automatically banned by the system for failing audits on June 20th and June 14th. That's what 'repeatedly failing audits' refers to.

Treat every review as a 'test'. They all are.